# Структура данных mp4 и получение нужного пикселя

Tags: java, потоки-данных, mp4, rgb

У меня есть видео в формате mp4. В коде оно представлено в виде потока байтов. Мне нужно получить RGB пикселя в конкретных координатах и конкретном кадре. Как я это могу сделать? Как я понял для этого надо знать каким образом видео кодируется. И возможно, этот поток байтов придется преобразовать, но если возможно, то лучше без преобразований. Мне важно сохранить память. Если напрямую из потока битов очень сложно достать цвет пикселя, тогда может есть какие-то библиотеки для этого?